# How do I use JSON.parse in Internet Explorer 9 with json2.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using JSON.parse to turn a JSON string into a JSON object. It works in Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari but not in IE9.  Everytime I use JSON.parse Internet Explorer throws a "SCRIPT1014: Invalid character" error. I have included json2.js into the script since JSON.parse isn't supported in IE8 but to no avail does it still work. How can I make this work?

```
function run() {
        $("#testing").ajaxSubmit({
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var parsedjson = JSON.parse(data);
                var truejson = parsedjson[0];
            }
        });
    }

LOG: <pre>[{"group":null,"name":"lion.jpg","type":"image/png","size":5269,"progress":"1.0","url":"/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx?f=lion.jpg","thumbnail_url":"data:image/png;base64,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","delete_url":"/Upload/UploadHandler.ashx?f=lion.jpg","delete_type":"DELETE","error":null}]</pre>
```

Comment: `json2.js` Will only change JSON.parse if it doesn't already exist natively in the browser.  So including `json2.js` shouldn't cause any error to show.  Can you post an example of the data returned from the server?  It sounds like something isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: Is there some weird empty space character in the output? Have you taken the output and shrink it down until you found the problem?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using $.getJSON?

Comment: cause i'm submitting a form of input type file via ajax, which $.getJSON doesn't support

Comment: Why not use the `dataType: 'json'` option to `ajaxSubmit()`?

Comment: @Barmar Because submitting files using ajax is not possible.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. I didn't say to change the function used to submit the file, I said to add an option to it.

Comment: the "LOG" statement in the code is the console.log of the data returned. @Barmar, specifying "json" for the dataType will not work with the jQuery Ajax Form Plugin when submitting files via ajax

Comment: the response of the data returned has to be plain text since i'm returning base64 encoding features

Comment: The LOG statement is `console.log(truejson)`, we need to see `console.log(data)`. And why won't `dataType: 'json'` work? I see it documented [here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object).

Comment: You can also try jQuery's JSON parser, `$.parseJSON()`.

Comment: didn't work...same error

Comment: Are `<pre>` and `</pre>` really in the JSON string? That's not valid JSON.

Comment: i'm aware of that. the <pre> tags are added by internet explorer for some odd reason...when i console

Comment: From the documentation of $.ajaxSubmit(): "This is fine if the response type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work as well if the response type is script or JSON, both of which often contain characters that need to be repesented using entity references when found in HTML markup." Source: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload. This applies to IE9. Is this what you're running in to?

Comment: yeah i think so. all i have to do is remove the <pre> tags that internet explorer throws on and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to remove the "pre" tags surrounding the returned json string as Internet Explorer throws these tags on in order to preserve the structure of the text. The Form Plugin does work with Internet Explorer but only for same domain cases. CORS unfortunately is not supported by IE9. Solved the problem by doing this....

```
function imageUploader() {
        $("#testing").ajaxSubmit({
            success: function (data) {
                if (jQuery.browser.msie == true) {
                    var newdata = data.replace('<pre>', '');
                    var newdata2 = newdata.replace('</pre>', '');
                    var parsedjson = JSON.parse(newdata2);
                    var truejson = parsedjson[0];
                    var image = "<img src=" + truejson.thumbnail_url + " alt=" + truejson.name + "/>";
                    $("div#previewIe").html(image);
                } else {
                    var parsedjson = JSON.parse(data);
                    var truejson = parsedjson[0];
                    var image = "<img src=" + truejson.thumbnail_url + " alt=" + truejson.name + "/>";
                    $("div#previewIe").html(image);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the jQuery Form Plugin. As stated by Kyle, json2.js is irrelevant here.

IE9 [does not support submitting files via ajax](http://caniuse.com/xhr2).

So the jQuery Form Plugin submits the form to a hidden iframe as a workaround, [which has its limitations](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload). These limitations are what you're running in to.

> This is fine if the response type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work as well if the response type is script or JSON, both of which often contain characters that need to be repesented using entity references when found in HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery.browser** This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.

see:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/